# sys.columns access issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am wondering for SQL Server authentication mode (not Windows authentication mode), how to grant non-sa user to be able to access this view?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link below

http://blog.gre-sqlserver-solutions.com/2010/02/sql-agent-giving-non-sa-users.html

and also

http://www.sypron.nl/grant_sa.html

**UPDATE**

Create the user. Open sql management studio with sa user, right click to a view you want to give permission, find permissions part and just add created non-sa sql user. 
There's also Security->Users Folder in your DB tree, where you can create user.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi hgulyan, thanks! The document is long, could you point me which command should I use please?

Comment: You want the user to select any view?

Comment: @hgulyan, script in your reply seems dealing with SQL Agent? But my question has nothing to do with SQL Agent, just want to grant non-sa user to have permission to access view sys.columns. Any comments?